# Circle to fill a container animation

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations, css-transitions

I'm trying to mimic the animation that happens when you click the icon to open up the menu from over at https://www.fpp.net/contact/ (top right, the circle thingie) but mine looks janky and not because of easing.

It (visually) seems that they use some kind of rectangular overlay and the circle simply fills that. That rectangular overlay is the width and height of the browser, so it seems like the circle is transforming into a rectangle.

I've tried, but to no avail:

```js
$('#circle').on('click', (event) => {
  $(event.currentTarget).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

```css
body {
  
}

#circle {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999999999;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  transition: transform 0.75s ease;
  transform-origin: center;
}

#circle.clicked {
  transform: scale(150);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="circle"></div>
</body>
```

As you can see, the difference in their animation and mine is that theirs expands in a natural way while mine expands...weirdly?

To add to injury, because it expands so much, it adds to the browser height / width.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `box-shadow` instead `transform` and a pseudo a bit smaller  to avoid the buggy gap around the container and the shadow;

```js
$('#circle').on('click', (event) => {
  $(event.currentTarget).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

```css
body {}

#circle {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999999999;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  background-color: black;
}

#circle::before {
  content: '';
  height: 28px;
  width: 28px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  border-radius: inherit;
  transition: 0.75s ease;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0vw;
}

#circle.clicked::before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 200vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="circle"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: @DanielM it's an hint to avoid scrollbar , dig in it ;)

Comment: Awesome! Can you explain a bit the usage of `200vw`?

Comment: @DanielM it is to make sure it will cover the whole screen. especially from top left to bottom right . it means 200% of the window's width. On a portrait mode , it might not be enough, you could turn it to 200vmax. some reading to help you from my average english ;) : https://web-design-weekly.com/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/